# How to add days, years, hours to boost::ptime?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, boost, timestamp

For example i have ptime("2000-10-10 00:00:00"). How i can add to this ptime? For example "0001-00-01 00:00:00" - one year and one day, and i can use only this format cuz i get string like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" or in timestamp_t(uin64_t). In main func i write example how i see this.

```
constexpr const char format[] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

bt::ptime from_string_dtime(const std::string& s);

class date_time
{
public:
    date_time() = default;
    date_time(const std::string& dtime);
    date_time(const bt::ptime& ptime);
    
    ~date_time() = default;
    
    api::timestamp_t to_timestamp();

public:

    friend date_time operator+ (const date_time& lv, uint64_t rv);
    
private:
    bt::ptime d_time;
};


    bt::ptime from_string_dtime(const std::string& s)
{
    bt::ptime pt;
    std::istringstream is(s);
    is.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    is.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new bt::time_input_facet(format)));
    is >> pt;
    return pt;
}

date_time::date_time(const std::string& dtime)
:   d_time(from_string_dtime(dtime))
{}

date_time::date_time(const bt::ptime& ptime)
:   d_time(ptime)
{}

api::timestamp_t date_time::to_timestamp() {     
    const bt::ptime epoch = bt::from_time_t(0);
    bt::time_duration duration = d_time - epoch;
    return duration.total_seconds(); 
}

date_time operator+ (const date_time& lv, uint64_t rv)
{
    return date_time(lv.d_time + bt::milliseconds(rv));
}

int main()
{
    nup::core::date_time dtime("0000-00-01 00:00:01"); // Exception here, i understand why, but idk how resolve
    nup::core::date_time dtime2("2004-04-22 00:00:01");
    nup::core::date_time dtime3("2004-04-23 00:00:02");
    
    //i want smth like this
    (dtime + dtime2) == dtime(3)

}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this class has extensive documentation, like all boost classes. Have you tried reading it? At least in case of days and hours you have actual code examples in boost's documentation, and I'm sure that a little bit of digging will establish the appropriate logic for years. Knowing where to find and how to read technical documentation is something that every C++ developer must know how to do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Exactly why i'm here, i read and found nothing about my problem

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Man i told you what i read this, read boost documentation and found nothing about my problem, I'm sorry that I didn't specify what exactly I was reading, I thought from the context (you're talking about boost) it's obvious

Comment: Yes, and when I used Google to search for "boost ptime", I easily found Boost's documentation, and a few seconds' worth of browsing found the information needed to add days, hours, etc... to a boost::ptime. What boost documentation of boost::ptime did you read, specifically?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure why the response needs to be this harsh. Yes, superficially this might look like a "read the docs for me" question, but... have you **tried**? I think the crux is that you have to _read_ the question deeply to see what the real issue is, instead of how the question (and specifically the question code) is presented. I think people need to bring a lot more patience to this site (or refrain from voting)

Comment: Besides, if you really thought the question was answered in the docs (which it isn't) - why not provide a link to it? (Granted OP could have done the same, as you correctly pointed out)

Comment: What's so harsh about confirming exactly what documentation the other person read? Unless we're on the same page we'll just be talking past each other, @sehe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's reasonable to ask what documentation OP referenced. If you read your own comments, you might see you went quite some ways beyond. In fact, I only see you asking "What boost documentation of boost::ptime did you read, specifically?" at the end of a third, ranty, comment that you posted ~15 hours after the first. In the mean time the question was allowed to collect down-votes at an accelerated pace because a 100k user implicitly labeled it as RTFM. Did you see the answer, I'd love to know what precise part of the documentation answered it.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to change the course of the universe, just making you reflect. God knows I've been made to reflect on my own actions on this site countless times. It's all good. Thanks for contributing at all!

Comment: I have no idea how one could get such insight into the reasoning behind ... just two downvotes. I wouldn't describe that as some kind of a Shakespearean tragedy. And I don't see myself going much beyond a gentle reminder that, well, there's documentation for this. Because I thought that there was a definite disinterest in doing any kind of a research, and a very likely chance that this was a case of a "myth victim" (referring to one of my stock comments). I'm pretty sure now that I was right, given the lack of forthcoming confirmation (I'll be surprised if one turns up).

Comment: You know, from what you're saying, I should attach a screenshot of me sitting on boost.org looking for answers so that a random stackoverflow guy doesn't say that I "wasn't interested", trust me friend, I spent over ~6 hours, and if not for the burning deadlines, I would probably have solved the problem by spending more time, but alas. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: And you decided instead of answering a question that is "banal" for you, as you usually do, for example, I see your answer, roughly speaking, about the difference between push and emplace, the Internet is full of answers to this question, but for some reason you instead say, for example, like me, "go see the documentation", you answer that question. You took 2 people's time to talk about useless things.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you have looked all over https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html and you always just seemed to overlook the "Time Math" chapter, with actual code that, for example, gives literal examples of date math, and "simple calculation" like "date tommorrow = today + days(1);"? I guess I got lucky and found it right away.

Comment: P.S. There were a number of very fundamental differences between the kind of a question that was the push vs. emplace one, and the kind of a question this one was. The other one was clearly from a newbie, and someone who showed an honest a desire to learn C++ ***by themselves***. Here, the question includes shown code that demonstrates advanced C++ concepts. That code above is not the kind of a code that I'd expect to see from a beginner, but from someone with advanced C++ skills. It is not unreasonable to expect someone like that to be able to find and read the docs themselves.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Please. "I don't see myself going much beyond a gentle reminder" - _immediately_ followed up with "I thought that there was a definite disinterest in doing any kind of a research"? If you can't see the contradiction there, well. In the words of a respected SO contributor "". I dont know what "myth victim" refers to (neither [does Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22myth+victim%22)), but is clear that it is you doing the assumptions. I submit that having stock responses in the first place might prime oneself for knee-jerk responses?

Comment: Finally, "I'm pretty sure now that I was right" tells me you still haven't read (understood) the question. No Shakespearian drama, just a note that our behavior matters beyond how we feel about it. Have a good day. Hope you also got my thanks, we can't monitor these tags without the help, and many times your comments *do* help get the needed clarifications. So keep on the good work.

Comment: (gah I botched my edits. The empty quotation should have been "I have no idea how one could get such insight")

Comment: I'm not worried much about any knee-jerk responses. I'm a big boy. Sticks and stones, etc... I do not require any safe spaces, from meanie words.

Comment: Duh. Of course you don't run any risk here. That's the point. You could be more aware about the power balance. You do you, and I'm happy to disagree. Best we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nup::core::date_time dtime("0000-00-01 00:00:01"); // Exception here, i understand why, but idk how resolve
```

The problem is that you're trying to treat something that is **not** a date-time as a... `date_time`. Parse a duration instead! Here's an example using Spirit to parse the fixed format from the question only:

```
struct duration {
    unsigned          y, m, d;
    bt::time_duration tod;
};

duration parse_duration(std::string_view sv) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    static const x3::uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 4, 4> u4{};
    static const x3::uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 2, 2> u2{};

    duration result;
    unsigned short H, M, S;
    auto tied = std::tie(result.y, result.m, result.d, H, M, S);

    if (!x3::parse(begin(sv), end(sv),
                  u4 >> '-' >> u2 >> '-' >> u2 >> ' ' >> //
                      u2 >> ':' >> u2 >> ':' >> u2 >> x3::eoi,
                  tied))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid time duration");
    }
    result.tod = bt::hours(H) + bt::minutes(M) + bt::seconds(S);
    return result;
}
```

Now you can implement `operator+`:

```
friend date_time operator+(const date_time& lv, duration const& rv) {
    return lv.d_time + //
        bg::years(rv.y) + bg::months(rv.m) + bg::days(rv.d) + rv.tod;
}
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e82946ef1cffb8f)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <sstream>

namespace bg = boost::gregorian;
namespace bt = boost::posix_time;

namespace nup::core {
    constexpr const char format[] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

    bt::ptime from_string_dtime(const std::string& s);

    struct duration {
        unsigned          y, m, d;
        bt::time_duration tod;
    };

    duration parse_duration(std::string_view sv) {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        static const x3::uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 4, 4> u4{};
        static const x3::uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 2, 2> u2{};

        duration result;
        unsigned short H, M, S;
        auto tied = std::tie(result.y, result.m, result.d, H, M, S);

        if (!x3::parse(begin(sv), end(sv),
                      u4 >> '-' >> u2 >> '-' >> u2 >> ' ' >> //
                          u2 >> ':' >> u2 >> ':' >> u2 >> x3::eoi,
                      tied))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid time duration");
        }
        result.tod = bt::hours(H) + bt::minutes(M) + bt::seconds(S);
        return result;
    }

    class date_time {
      public:
        date_time() = default;
        ~date_time() = default;
        date_time(const std::string& dtime)
            : d_time(from_string_dtime(dtime)) {}

        date_time(const bt::ptime& ptime) : d_time(ptime) {}

        auto to_timestamp() {
            const bt::ptime   epoch    = bt::from_time_t(0);
            bt::time_duration duration = d_time - epoch;
            return duration.total_seconds();
        }

      public:
        friend date_time operator+(const date_time& lv, duration const& rv) {
            return lv.d_time + //
                bg::years(rv.y) + bg::months(rv.m) + bg::days(rv.d) + rv.tod;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, date_time const& dt) {
            return os << dt.d_time;
        }

      private:
        bt::ptime d_time;
    };

    bt::ptime from_string_dtime(const std::string& s) {
        bt::ptime          pt;
        std::istringstream is(s);
        is.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
        is.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(),
                             new bt::time_input_facet(format)));
        is >> pt;
        return pt;
    }

} // namespace nup::core

int main()
{
    auto dtime = nup::core::parse_duration("0000-00-01 00:00:01");

    nup::core::date_time dtime2("2004-04-22 00:00:01");
    nup::core::date_time dtime3("2004-04-23 00:00:02");

    std::cout << "dtime:            " << dtime.y          << "-"   << dtime.m << "-" << dtime.d << " " << dtime.tod << "\n";
    std::cout << "dtime2:           " << dtime2           << "\n";
    std::cout << "(dtime2 + dtime): " << (dtime2 + dtime) << "\n";
    std::cout << "dtime3:           " << dtime3           << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
dtime:            0-0-1 00:00:01
dtime2:           2004-Apr-22 00:00:01
(dtime2 + dtime): 2004-Apr-23 00:00:02
dtime3:           2004-Apr-23 00:00:02
```